# Saving a inherited class to MongoDB (C#), but I only want to serialize the base class members

Tags: c#, mongodb

Let's say for example I have the following classes in my C# project:

```
public class AnimalContainer
{
   string SomeData {get; set;}
   AnimalBase Animal {get; set;}
}

public class AnimalBase 
{
   string Name {get; set;}
   int Age {get; set;}
}

public class Cat : AnimalBase
{
   string FurColor {get; set;}
}
```

Now if I create a new `Cat`, place it inside `AnimalContainer` and store it to MongoDB, the **entire cat class** will be saved to Mongo, and not just the base class members.

(Edit) In the said example, the data on Mongo could look something like this:

```
{
   "SomeData": "x",
   "Animal": {
      "Name": "Cat Damon",
      "Age": 3,
      "FurColor": "Black"
    }
}
```

I am wondering, how can I make sure that only the base class is saved to Mongo versus the behavior I'm currently seeing.

Comment: If you are not saving Cat in db, why not create AnimalBase instance only.

Comment: @nvartak I'm saving `Cat` in other places, but in this specific instance I only want to save the subset of data present in the base class

Answer (score -2):

I found once a slideshow about streams in Java, how to do such thinge like Streaming Objects over the network or save them to something.
I would credit it, if i would find it. But however I found his Arguments quite good why one should not do this in the way you do.
He suggested to not stream objects directly but to create a second object which holds the data you want to save.

E.g. if you want to save/send an user object:

```
//some constructor which copies the values for stremin
UserStreamingObject DecoratorObject = new UserStreamingObject(User);
Stream.send(DecoratorObject);
//other Site
Stream.receive(DecoratorObject);
User bla = new User(DecoratorObject);
```

I would suggest that you do the the following, since I am not familiar with C# I will explain a little bit abstract.
Make some kind of Copy Constructor, some method that creates an Animal Instance from its Child Classes and Save this one. You will have to save the actual type somewhere for reflection. Since you may save data in the databse which should not be there and you may save large trees in the database if C# streams referenced objects (like java does).
You might not only save large amounts of data, but even save data you do not want to save and/or should not be saved there, like passwords or personal data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but beyond that, is irrelevant advice - with a little research, you'd see that by the time the MongoDb driver is talking over the network to the MongoDb server, the content has been trimmed down and serialised.